# UITableView deletion not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to delete a row from a `UITableView`.
My `UITableView` is populated from a `NSMutableArray` named `TableData`.
When I am deleting a row and reloading the tableview, it shows that the last row has been removed [**not the selected row**].
But when I `NSLog()` the contents of the mutable array it shows that the selected row has been removed.

This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [TableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < [TableData count]; i++) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Value at %d :%@", i, [TableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: As a matter of Objective-C convention, the first letter of your variables should be lowercase, not uppercase (re: your `TableData` variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `reloadData` instead, call `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];`.